# C++ keyboard hook CTRL key gets stuck

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, hook, clipboard

I'm looking to rewrite <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on my Windows 10 machine to add some additional functionality.

I'm able to copy and paste correctly and have successfully created a keyboard hook to execute my code after these keys are pressed but I'm having an issue after I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while my program is running, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> continuously acts as if it's held down. Even after I terminate the program entirely, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> continues to act as if it's being held down until I logout of the computer entirely. What can I do to correct this?

Thanks!

Edit: after doing a bit of messing around, I can conclude any key gets stuck. Shift and caps lock get stuck as well.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        if (p->vkCode == 0x43 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-c is pressed
            WM_COPY;
        }
        else if (p->vkCode == 0x56 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-v is pressed
            OpenClipboard(NULL);
            char* buffer;
            buffer = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            CloseClipboard();
            cout << buffer;
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

int main()
{
    HHOOK keyBoard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg;

    while (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyBoard);
}
```

Comment: Your compiler warned you, that not all control paths of your hook procedure return a value. Those warnings are there to help you. Do not ignore them.

Comment: On a side note, your use of `GetClipboardData()` is all wrong. The return value is a `HANDLE` to movable memory owned by the clipboard, you can't just type-cast it like you are, you must use `GlobalLock()` instead. And either way, you can't access the data after you call `CloseClipboard()`, you need to copy the data before you close the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not put `return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam)` in `if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)`.

Modify:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        if (p->vkCode == 0x43 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-c is pressed
            WM_COPY;
        }
        else if (p->vkCode == 0x56 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-v is pressed
            OpenClipboard(NULL);
            char* buffer;
            buffer = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            CloseClipboard();
            cout << buffer;
        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```