# C++ clipboard queue pasting random results?

Tags: c++, winapi, queue, hook, clipboard

I'm trying to make a clipboard queue, allowing me to copy multiple things and then paste them FIFO. To do so, I'm using with Windows API as well as a basic keyboard hook to detect ctrl+c and ctrl+v. My code seems to work however I seem to constantly get a random output from the queue.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector> 


using namespace std;
vector<char*> clipboardQueue; 
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        if (p->vkCode == 0x43 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-c is pressed
            WM_COPY;
            Sleep(500);
            OpenClipboard(NULL);
            char* buffer;
            buffer = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            CloseClipboard();
            clipboardQueue.push_back(buffer);
            cout << buffer << " copied!\n";
            cout << "clipboard size: " << clipboardQueue.size() << "\n";
        }
        else if (p->vkCode == 0x56 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-v is pressed
            if (clipboardQueue.size() > 0) {
                const char* output = clipboardQueue[0];
                const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
                HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
                memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
                GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                OpenClipboard(0);
                EmptyClipboard();
                SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
                CloseClipboard();
                WM_PASTE;
                clipboardQueue.erase(clipboardQueue.begin());
                cout << output << " pasted!\n";
                cout << "clipboard size: " << clipboardQueue.size() << "\n";
            }
        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    OpenClipboard(NULL);
    EmptyClipboard();
    CloseClipboard();
    HHOOK keyBoard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, NULL);
    MSG msg;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyBoard);
}
```

Using this code when copying "one, two, three, four, five" my outputs seem to be random with occassional missing keys entirely:

---

three
three
three
    ?
five

---

one
    ?
three
    ?
five

---

?
four
four
four
five

Comment: *The clipboard controls the handle that the GetClipboardData function returns, not the application. The application should copy the data immediately. The application must not free the handle nor leave it locked. The application must not use the handle after the EmptyClipboard or CloseClipboard function is called*

Comment: [Using the Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard).

Comment: thank you for the reply, can u please elaborate a bit more? I’m a bit confused by your explaination

Comment: Using a keyboard hook to look for CTRL-C is the wrong way to detect when things are copied to the clipboard. Use a clipboard monitor instead via `SetClipboardViewer()` or `AddClipboardFormatListener()`. See [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents) on MSDN for details.  And as I told you earlier in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836869/), you are misusing `GetClipboardData()`

Comment: For what you are attempting to do, when you do detect something being placed on the clipboard, you might consider clearing the clipboard after grabbing the data, and then use [Delay Rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations#delayed-rendering) to let apps paste data from your queue. Then you don't need to hook CTRL-V anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your reply. I've read through the MSDN and I'm still having a bit of confusion. I've experimented with removing my ctrlc wm_keydown and added a WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE. I don't see it being triggered on a cliboard change though. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: [WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate): *"To register a **window to receive this message**, use the [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) function."* You need a window to receive that message. It doesn't magically show up in a keyboard hook.

Comment: And since you already have a message loop anyway, it would be trivial to create a hidden message-only window for purposes of interacting with the clipboard.

Comment: @AlexRodriguez Have you tried the code sample in my answer? Feel free let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Key edits:**

1. When copy data to clipboard using `ctrl + c` there will sent a **[`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) message which you can use to monitor `ctrl + c` operations**. But there is no related message to monitor paste `control + v` operation so I keep hook part for `control + v`.
2. I can **reproduce "outputs seem to be random" issue** and solve it using array instead of `std::vector`.
3. Create a **message-only window** if you don't need a interact UI.
4. Add a new **custom clipboard format `MY_CLIPBOARD_FORMAT`** to indicate this is set data cased `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` message not actual `control + v` operation.

The following is just an example implement for your use case you can refer to:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
#define MY_CLIPBOARD_FORMAT (CF_PRIVATEFIRST + 1)

// Global Variables:
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
static int index = 0;
static char dataArry[10][10] = {};


// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    DWORD errorCode;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_QUEUECLIPBOARDDATA, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);

    // Register window class
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex = {};
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;

    ATOM cls = RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    errorCode = GetLastError();
    // Create a message-only window
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, szWindowClass, szTitle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        errorCode = GetLastError();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Set keyboard hook
    HHOOK keyBoard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, NULL);

    // Register a clipboard format listener 
    if (!AddClipboardFormatListener(hWnd))
        errorCode = GetLastError();


    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        if (p->vkCode == 0x56 && GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) { // ctrl-v is pressed

            if(index <= 0)
                return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

            static int i = 0;
            if (i < index)
            {
                const char* output = dataArry[i];
                const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
                HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
                memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
                GlobalUnlock(hMem);
                OpenClipboard(0);
                EmptyClipboard();
                SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);

                // Set custom defined format to indicate paste operation
                SetClipboardData(MY_CLIPBOARD_FORMAT, NULL);
                CloseClipboard();
                OutputDebugStringA("\n pasted!\n");
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                i = 0;
                index = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD errorCode;
    HANDLE clipObj = NULL;
    char* lptstr = NULL;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA("\nWM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE\n");

            // Empty clipboard casue this WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE, actually no new data copied
            if (IsClipboardFormatAvailable(MY_CLIPBOARD_FORMAT))
                break;

            if (!IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT))
                break;

            if (!OpenClipboard(hWnd))
            {
                errorCode = GetLastError();
                break;
            }

            clipObj = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            if(NULL == clipObj)
            {
                errorCode = GetLastError();
                break;
            }

            lptstr = (char*)GlobalLock(clipObj);
            if (lptstr != NULL)
            {
                OutputDebugStringA(lptstr);

                memcpy(dataArry[index++], lptstr, strlen(lptstr));

                GlobalUnlock(lptstr);
            }
            CloseClipboard();
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```